# How do you tab down in bas on a macbook Pro?

Tags: bash

If I'm going through a large list of git diffs in terminal, how do I tab down via half-pages in a Mac Pro? Traditionally you would hold `shift + page down`, but the new Mac pros have a `fn` key and no page down button. Is there a quick way to tab downwards in bash on the new Macs?

Comment: This is a usage question, not a software development question; Stack Overflow's scope is strictly limited to questions that are **unique** to software development. Consider [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [apple.se].

Comment: (In particular, this is a question about terminal usage, and bash has no control of the terminal its output is displayed in, so it isn't even really a bash question at all!)

Answer (score -1):

Fn + Cmd + Arrow Up or Arrow Down will scroll a full page, not a half page.  If this is not sufficient, you can use [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/) to scroll an arbitrary amount, see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268627).

Comment: This didn't work, but `fn + command + down` ended up doing the trick.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "are not about programming as defined in the help center".